# Add .xll as AddIn to Excel

Tags: python, excel, powershell, ms-office, office-addins

I got a .xll file that I can easily add to excel by doing this:
*Options > Addins > Browse > double click .xll file*
It gets imported + activated (and it remains in  my excel addins every time I close and open Excel).

This is the manual way I try to replace with a script.

**PowerShell**

```
$excel=New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.RegisterXLL("C:\temp\v-0.0.1-20210906\LS-ZmqRtd-AddIn64.xll")
$excel.Visible = "$True"
#$excel.Quit()
```

This will create an instance of Excel, register the XLL (I get a "true" in my console) and show the created instance. But when I then go to AddIns, the AddIn isn't there.

**Python**

```
xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
xl.RegisterXLL(
    "C:/Users/michael.k/Desktop/v-0.0.1-20210906/LS-ZmqRtd-AddIn64.xll"
)
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/michael.k/Desktop/v-0.0.1-20210906/Test.xlsx")
```

But this behaves like the Powershell script.

So.. how can I add my .xll file into Excel to stay there ***permanently***? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you also need to use `$excel.AddIns.Add("LS-ZmqRtd-AddIn64.xll").Installed = $true` right after the `$excel.RegisterXLL(..)` line

Comment: Hey @Theo .. thanks for your reply.
I've seen this in an *.xla guide as well, sadly for me this isn't working.
I get an error saying "The Add property of the AddIns object cannot be assigned."..

Comment: How are you using that `.Add()` method? You should only supply the Name there, not the whole file path.

Comment: I'm using it likes this: `$excel.AddIns.Add("LS-ZmqRtd-AddIn64.xll").Installed = $true`

Comment: You might try `$excel.AddIns.Add("LS-ZmqRtd-AddIn64.xll", $true).Installed = $true` or the `AddIns2` object instead.

Comment: Sadly the line you have me doesn't work as well. It still says that the property cannot be assigned. AddIns2? How would that be executed!? Can you give ma an example? :)

Comment: `$excel.AddIns2.Add("LS-ZmqRtd-AddIn64.xll", $true).Installed = $true`. If that too doesn't work, I'm sorry but then I cannot help..

Comment: Thank you. This results into "The Add method of the AddIns2 object could not be executed." .. I have no idea why it isn't working. Thanks anyway. Maybe someone else has an idea!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the link Charles Williams gave me, I was able to do it a little bit different.

You can easily create a registry key to let excel know that it should run the .xll-file.

```
# initializing new variables
$req_path = Get-Item -Path Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property
$newest_version = (Get-ChildItem -Path I:\Software\LS-ZmqRtd\Test\ -Directory | sort lastwritetime | Select -Last 1).Name
$full_path_new_version = '/R "I:\Software\LS-ZmqRtd\Test\'+$newest_version+'\LS-ZmqRtd-AddIn64.xll"'
$only_opens = @()
[bool]$ls_zmqrtd_found = $false
[bool]$ls_zmqrtd_updated = $false
$count_opens = 0

# welcome message
echo ">> checking if the LS-ZmqRtd addin is installed and has the newest version.."
Start-Sleep -s 5

# check if there are regkeys that contain 'OPEN' in their name (if yes, add them to the $only_opens array)
foreach ($entry in $req_path)
{
    if ($entry -like "OPEN*")
    {
        $only_opens += $entry
    }
}

if (!$only_opens) # check if array is empty (if yes, add the new regkey for LS-ZmqRtd)
{
    echo ">> the LS-ZmqRtd addin couldn't be found.. adding it to excel now."
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options -Name OPEN -PropertyType String -Value $full_path_new_version
    echo ">> addin was added to excel successfully - this requires Excel to be fully closed and re-opened."
}
else # if no, check if one of the regkeys have the LS-ZmqRtd path value (if found, set $ls_zmqrtd_found to true - else remain false)
{  
    foreach ($open in $only_opens)
    {
        $value = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options" -Name $open).$open
        if ($value -eq $full_path_new_version)
        {
            $ls_zmqrtd_found = $true
        }
        else
        {
            echo ">> found an old version of LS-ZmqRtd.. replacing it with the new one now."
            Start-Sleep -s 2
            Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options -Name $open -Value $full_path_new_version
            $ls_zmqrtd_updated = $true
        }
        $count_opens += 1
    }


    if ($ls_zmqrtd_found -eq $true) # if $ls_zmqrtd_found is true, there is nothing to do
    {
        echo ">> found that the newest version of LS-ZmqRtd is already installed - nothing to do here."
    }
    elseif ($ls_zmqrtd_updated -eq $true)
    {
        echo ">> updated LS-ZmqRtd to the newest version - an update requires Excel to be fully closed and re-opened."
    }
    else # if $ls_zmqrtd_found is false, increment the last OPEN's number by 1 and add the new reqkey for LS-ZmqRtd
    {
        $new_reg_key = "OPEN" + ($count_opens+1)
        echo ">> the LS-ZmqRtd addin couldn't be found.. adding it to excel now."
        Start-Sleep -s 2
        New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options -Name $new_reg_key -PropertyType String -Value $full_path_new_version
        echo ">> addin was added to excel successfully - this requires Excel to be fully closed and re-opened."
    }
}
```

This script checks if the .xll-File is already named in a registry key.

- If yes and it has our newest provided version -> do nothing
- If yes but the version is old -> update the registrey key's value
- If no -> create the registry key and set the value to our newest
  provided version

Answer (score 1):

I would either:

- Add some VBA to the workbook open event to register the XLL, this will work for a specific workbook
- Write the registry key for the XLL (note Excel must be closed whilst you write the registry key)
  Here is a link to a LUA script to do that: this will show you how and you can rewrite in the language you want to use.
  https://jkp-ads.com/articles/AddinsAndSetupFactory.asp

Comment: Thank you Charles, really appreciate the link! That gave me enough information to create a workaround myself.